# How Should I find back the missing codes in a flat file?

Tags: sublimetext, flat-file

The flat file containing codes and daily notes were deleted by mistake. I used `with open(file, 'w')` in python code and erase the file to a blank one. Since I edited it with sublime text, is there anything I can do to find back the deleted codes?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime doesn't maintain backups of files that you work with unless you've installed a third party package/plugin that does that for you (for example [AutoBackups](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoBackups)).

As such, unless you had already done that, the data in your file is unfortunately probably irretrievable at this point.